# Sums over individual days

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have pulled out the consumption of gas for the first day of 2007. The time is in UTC, so the day starts from 5 in the morning and runs for 24 hours.

```
select sum(b.kwh) as consumption
from BATimeSeries b
where 
    b.companyNo = 1 and 
    b.DayTime >= '2007-01-01 05:00:00.000' and 
    b.DayTime < '2007-01-02 05:00:00.000'
```

Here it just gives a table with a single row (consumption) which gives the consumption in kWh for that day. But I would really like to have a table that spans over a period of time, for example a week, month or year. Each row has two columns: day, consumption, which lists each day in the interval and the sum of consumption for that specific day. I can't figure out to aggregate over days and then for each of these days to give the sum for that day. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` should suffice;

```
SELECT DAY(daytime - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) day, SUM(b.kwh) consumption
FROM BATimeSeries b
WHERE b.companyNo = 1
GROUP BY day;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb928d/1).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DATE(b.DayTime),sum(b.kwh) as consumption
FROM BATimeSeries b
WHERE
    b.companyNo = 1 and 
    b.DayTime >= '2007-01-01 05:00:00.000' and 
    b.DayTime < '2007-01-02 05:00:00.000'
GROUP BY DATE(b.DayTime)
```

If you remove the where, you should get from all the days.

```
SELECT DATE(b.DayTime),sum(b.kwh) as consumption
FROM BATimeSeries b
WHERE b.companyNo = 1 and 
GROUP BY DATE(b.DayTime)
```